# CSS draws differently on Mac OSX? (menu bars get pushed one pixel, pushing last button down a row)

Tags: css, macos, osx-lion

For years I've noticed something odd about websites on a Mac, regardless of the browser used. On OS X, I frequently notice CSS responding differently.

I most often see it visually when the last button is pushed down to the next row in a menu because it's a pixel too large. Why does this happen?

Example: http://www.dynamicprint.ca/
[image]

Comment: Btw, I've encountered this issue on Firefox, Opera and Safari on various OS X versions (10.5, 10.6, 10.7)

Comment: Doesn't happen here in OSX in Chrome or Safari. Suspect it's your font size.

Comment: You're right, I guess it's a **firefox only** issue..  
I reduced my font size from times 16 to 14, but still no dice in Firefox 11.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update your css with below css rules and you will see the problem is gone.

http://www.dynamicprint.ca/ (line 81)

```
div.ys_menu a {
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 39px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 22px 18px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

SS:

[image]